# Hyperledger Fabric cryptogen and configtxgen not working

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to create the "crypto matrial" of my hyperledger fabric network using the cryptogen command line but I get "command not found" as result

My command line :  user@ubuntu:~/go/src/github.com/*****/fabric-samples/bin$ cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yam
cryptogen: command not found

Please i need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because cryptogen binary is not available in PATH. Download the cryptogen and move the binary to some location in the PATH. Instructions for the same are available in [fabric documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/install.html).

Answer (score 1):

Go to your test-network folder. After that set the PATH of hyperledger-fabric binary and config file.

> export PATH=${PWD}/../bin:$PATH
> export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/../config/

These commands are for the fabric-samples test network. You have modified it according to your folder structure.
After that try to run the below command

> [image: cryptogen version]